# Mysql query that use 3 different tables which contain data

Tags: sql, join

LINKS

|---------------------|------------------|
|         link        |     link_id      |
|---------------------|------------------|
|    [www.google.it](http://www.google.it)    |        1         |
|---------------------|------------------|
|    [www.yahoo.it](http://www.yahoo.it)     |        2         |
|---------------------|------------------|
|    [www.msn.it](http://www.msn.it)       |        3         |
|---------------------|------------------|
| [www.netscape.com](http://www.netscape.com)    |        4         |
|---------------------|------------------|

USERS

|---------------------|------------------|
|         user        |      user_id     |
|---------------------|------------------|
|          Micky      |        11        |
|---------------------|------------------|
|          Lupin      |        22        |
|---------------------|------------------|

USER VISITED

|---------------------|------------------|
|         user_id     |      link_id     |
|---------------------|------------------|
|          11         |        1         |
|---------------------|------------------|
|          22         |        3         |
|---------------------|------------------|

Answer (score 1):

I see Question and This is easy you see the query i wrote blow

SELECT links.link, links.link_id FROM links WHERE links.link_id NOT IN (SELECT Y.link_id FROM users X INNER JOIN user_visited Y ON X.user_id = Y.user_id WHERE X.user_id = 22);